# How can i stop mediaelent.js player

Tags: html, streaming, media-player, mediaelement.js

I stream webradio mpeg with MediaElement.js via shoutcast and it works. but when i click the stop button, the player stops not really, but it buffers the music. How can I stop the player permanently? can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers manage media buffering differently so it's very hard to stop buffering consistently.

Apart from setting `preload="none"` in your `video/audio` tag(s), a trick that would work in most browsers is to (re)load the media if this is stopped.

You could add an `event` listener and *trigger* the media reload if stopped (MEJS only includes the `pause` event, which seamlessly work) like :

```
$("audio").mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
        mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function (e) {
            mediaElement.load();
        }, false);
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YPb62/)**

**Note**: this is a workaround that may not work in all browsers.